# I cant close my realm instance on the correct thread

Tags: android, realm, rx-java

The following code throws an IllegalStateException that i am accessing realm on the wrong thread when i am trying to close the realm instance.

The exception is thrown when i am checking if the realm instance is closed in the closeRealm() method.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Realm access from incorrect thread. Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created.
                                                                               at io.realm.BaseRealm.isClosed(BaseRealm.java:441)
                                                                               at io.realm.Realm.isClosed(Realm.java:127)
                                                                               at com.zeyad.usecases.db.RealmManager.lambda$closeRealm$24(RealmManager.java:309)
                                                                               at com.zeyad.usecases.db.RealmManager$$Lambda$13.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                               at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

I am  trying to implement an offline 1st approach and i am missing fixing the realm closing on the correct thread. Here is my code please check it out and let me know whats the problem. Or for a better look here is a link to the code: https://github.com/Zeyad-37/UseCases/blob/api/usecases/src/main/java/com/zeyad/usecases/api/DataService.java

Thanks in advance.

```
HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("backgroundThread");
Handler backgroundHandler = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper());

public void getUsersOfflineFirst() {
    Observable<List> online = restApi.users().doOnNext(user -> {
        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        try {
            realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(user)));
        } finally {
            closeRealm(realm);
        }
    });
    return Observable.defer(() -> {
        Realm realm2 = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        return realm2.where(User.class).findAll().asObservable()
                .filter(results -> ((RealmResults) results).isLoaded())
                .map(users -> realm2.copyFromRealm((RealmResults) users))
                .doOnUnsubscribe(() -> closeRealm(realm2));
    }).flatMap(new Func1<List, Observable<List>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<List> call(List list) {
            if (!list.isEmpty())
                return Observable.just(list);
            else return online;
        }
    }).compose(applySchedulers());
}

private void closeRealm(Realm realm) {
    backgroundHandler.post(() -> {
        if (!realm.isClosed()) {
            realm.close();
            Log.d(RealmManager.class.getSimpleName(), "realm instance closed!");
        }
    });
}

private <T> Observable.Transformer<T, T> applySchedulers() {
    if (!handlerThread.isAlive())
        handlerThread.start();
    Scheduler backgroundThread = AndroidSchedulers.from(handlerThread.getLooper());
    return  observable -> observable.subscribeOn(backgroundThread)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .unsubscribeOn(backgroundThread);
}
```

Comment: The whole stack trace instead of just the error message would help narrow it down.

Comment: I added the full stacktrace.

Comment: Well you were right that is not very helpful at all! :D anyways I just think the background handler you are posting to isn't the thread you have the thread on. You might need to use `subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.from(handlerThread.getLooper())`, and don't forget to do `unsubscribeOn` on the same scheduler.

Comment: could you explain what do you mean by: "I just think the background handler you are posting to isn't the thread you have the thread on"

Comment: I mean you have the *Realm* on, it was a typo :p

Comment: I found the problem it was somewhere else in the code :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably not with the close but with the opening.
Both opening and closing `Realm` instance should happen at the same thread, as in Realm, **you must access Realm objects on the same thread** that doesn't  matter if it's close/open but any action on Realm Objects, as the docs says:

> Realm, RealmObject or RealmResults instances cannot be passed across
>   threads

My guess is that at the `online` `Observable` you are **opening** the Realm instance not on the handler thread (`Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();`) while all your close are happens at the background handler thread.

This happens because you're `online` `Observable` is flatMapped and no `Scheduler` is apply to it. so although the source `Observable` (`Observable.defer()`) is indeed subscribed as desired in the background thread, the online will subscribed at the thread that call the `getUsersOfflineFirst()` method which is probably not the background thread.

Comment: but the exception is thrown when i am trying to close the instance. i added the full stack trace to the question

Comment: edited the answer to add more information. it will raise on the close, as there is nothing wrong with the opening, and as the close is the other operation you do on other thread, you can create Realm object from any thread, the limitation is that you can pass Realm objects  between threads, and as I wrote it seems that you are opening it at different thread then closing , so you're passing it between thread.

Comment: you can try to add `subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.from(handlerThread.getLooper()‌​)` to the online `Observable` to see if it's solving the issue, and also add logs to all the places where you touch realm objects to see what thread it's done on to spot the issue.

Comment: I found the problem it was somewhere else in the code :)
I logged where the realm instance was open and closed then i was able to fix it easily